# Custom jQuery filter needs optimization

Tags: jquery, performance, filter

In the code below, friendBlocks has 800+ items that look like this:

```
<div class='block'>
    <span class='title'>Some Name</span>
    <img src='some.img' />
</div>
```

And I'm trying to filter them with the below code. It works, but is extremely slow and sometimes crashes the browser.

```
friendBlocks = friendform.find('.block');
filterFriends = function(text) {
    friendBlocks.each(function() {
        var block;
        block = $(this);
        if (block.children('.title').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0) {
            block.show();
        } else {
            block.hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Is there some way to optimize this and do the search more efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not apply the manipulation on each item in real-time! Clone the node, that contains the block divs, perform the operation, and then replace the original DOM.

Something like (not tested, just example):

```
friendform   = $('#container').clone();
friendBlocks = friendform.find('.block');
filterFriends = function(text) {
    friendBlocks.each(function() {
        var block;
        block = $(this);
        if (block.children('.title').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0) {
            block.show();
        } else {
            block.hide();
        }
    });
};
$('#container').replaceWith(friendform);
```

Comment: Could you give an example of that @Darhazer?

Comment: @adamyonk, I've added an example. Let me know if you need any further assistance. Note, the code assumes that all divs with class `block` are in a div with id `container`.

Answer (score 2):

This is noticeably much faster than your original code when tested in jsfiddle:

```
var blocks = $('div.block');
var foundBlocks = blocks.filter(function() {        
    return $('span.title', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0;
});    
foundBlocks.show();    
blocks.not(foundBlocks).hide();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zRbNK/3/)

I tried changing it so it cloned and then did the show/hide but I didn't notice any obvious difference in speed. Although this was chrome, other browsers may be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I'd code something like this;

```
$('.block .title').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0) { // not sure about here
            $(this).parent('div').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('div').hide();
        }
});
```

edit: code updated, not tried though. Coded this just to show selectors.

Comment: text.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) does not make sense

Comment: Yes I know , sadly I'm not very good at vanilla JS, I coded this just to show how I'd use the selectors.