# how facebook maintains a good speed for instant auto-suggestion

Tags: php, facebook, performance, performance-testing, database-performance

Facebook has the feature to show instant auto-suggestion result in-various situations such as : searching ,  message sending etc.

i think I have been correct in terming the functionality as 'auto-suggestion'.

If a user has 1000 friends and s/he wishes to send message to a friend , then facebook will suggest his/her name on typing a few characters.

My question is: While pulling the data out of database to find friends (or for any such situation) and then handling with it, which technique does FB use to maintain the speed in auto-suggestion?

Is it caching the variable  or what? I wish to know in details as i am planning to build a social networking site. My scripting language is php

Comment: trying to accept satisfactory answers

Comment: why negative ranking please ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a data structure like [patricia-trie](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Tree/PATRICIA/) or [ternary search tree](http://igoro.com/archive/efficient-auto-complete-with-a-ternary-search-tree/).

A `suggesttree` like: [suggesttree](http://suggesttree.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If I use memcahced from http://memcached.org , should or do  I need to go to those algorithms?

Comment: You will have have to use the data-structure even if you use memcached. Memcached is just for caching. The data structure will help when there are too many entries to go through. Keep the entries (with the use of a data structure) cached when a user login occurs. And use it only when the user tries to type into a text box set for auto-suggestion. i.e. this is concerned with AJAX & PHP. This will help with performance of the auto-suggestion (as you have mentioned: 'to maintain the speed in auto-suggestion?').

Answer (score 1):

I think a good chunk of it is not so much PHP, although facebook are known to use [hiphop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) to compile the PHP.

A more important factor IMO would be the database side of things. The query is probably as optimised as it can be, only getting back what it needs, caching will probably also come into play, i.e. the user's friends have been already retrieved, quite likely getting back the most frequently contacted friends. Also facebook have tons and tons of database servers, which can only help speed really.

Hope that helps

Comment: if not so much php then what?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed link is fixed now... Not so much PHP more so the database queries/setup. You could even say the javascript which is doing the ajax post and showing the autocomplete, plays a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-suggesting with 1000 or even 5000 entries is not that hard. You have to retrieve the whole friend list, and to store it in indexed javascript array (for example we did it using the first letter as index, so friends['a'] = [andrey, albert] ) and then you are actually searching in memory from a small subset.

The invite window is build in similar fashion - you build an index of names -> dom elements, you perform the dom manipulation offline - and you are attaching the results with only people that match the searched term.

The friendlist is most likely cached in memcached, and facebook warm up caches as early as it can - it does not wait to use the friend list in any way in order to put it in memcache. So - it's retrieven in memcached, stored in local storage and uses efficient JavaScript. No DB involved here.

P.S. I'm not speaking for facebook, but for a similar solution we've designed to handle fast auto-suggest / invite dialog on 5000+ entries.

Comment: '- you build an index of names -> dom elements, you perform the dom manipulation offline -' a bit more on dom manipulation? how can it be done offline?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942829/custom-jquery-filter-needs-optimization/6942905#6942905). By offline I mean do not apply anithing to the DOM rendered in the browser, but to an in-memory copy instead

Comment: 'No DB involved here' - so where are the profile records and such things stored?

Comment: ,' You have to retrieve the whole friend list, and to store it in indexed javascript array ' - when should I do it? The time the user needs to trvaerse through the friend list i.e. sending msg to a friend? If so, then for the first time , the whole friend list has to be retrieved from DB and then to be held in js array. So from the second time on and not at the first time, the user will get the enhanced speed. Is my concept right?