# Unresponsive javascript notification

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt

I have a situation where I render items from server in GWT grid on FireFox 3.6+. I have approximately 200 items and I load them in loop:

```
users = myService.getUsers();
for(User user : users){
    myPanel.addUser(user); // Pseudocode. Actually i add some labels and text fields...
}
```

It tooks a long time to change `DOM` in this loop, so I got "Unresponsive script" notification. But I can not refactor code or make pagination, I need all 200 items on 1 page loaded at once.

Are there any ways to suppress this notification? To notify browser that my script is not hang, but doing something useful?

**UPD Ok**, here is my code closer. It is a code from big project, and we have many custom components, so, I think, it has no real value.

```
    myService.getUsersDetails(searchCriteria, new MyCallback<List<User>>)
    {

        @Override
        protected void response(List<User> result)
        {
            gridExpanderPresenter.clear();
            int i = 0;
            for (User user: result)
            {
                UserDetailsView detailsView = detailsViewProvider.get();
                gridExpanderPresenter.setPresenter(UsersPresenter.this);
                gridExpanderPresenter.add(detailsView.asWidget()); //Here is DOM manipulation i mentioned
                if (i++ % 2 == 1)
                {
                    detailsView.setOdd(); //Setting style here
                }
                detailsView.setData(user);
            }
        }

    });
```

And I think [this](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html#incremental) can help me...

Comment: Are you sure that there is no cycling? Don't think that it's a big trouble for PC to proccess 200 items of javascript array... It would be great to look into your code closer, original, not pseudo.

Comment: That warning should be taken as an indication that your script needs to be revised. You should post the relevant code and perhaps somebody will see potential for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options:

- *batch* your updates using [`Scheduler.scheduleIncremental`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleIncremental%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand%29); rendering only 10 users or so at a time (don't worry, the `Scheduler` will run your code as many times as possible in a row before yielding, so it might actually render 50, 100 or 150 users at a time, and then continue 10ms (yes, milliseconds) after)
- switch to `CellTable`; this is a major refactoring, but it'll give you much better performance than anything else you could do based on widgets (`Label`, `TextBox`, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

You should add `User`s before attaching `myPanel` to the DOM, or if it's already attached and needs to be updated, remove `myPanel` from the DOM, add all users and reattach `myPanel`.

What happens when you add 200 users while myPanel is attached is that your browser has to update DOM 200 times which is quite costly (recalculating and repainting the screen).

Comment: Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942829/custom-jquery-filter-needs-optimization/6942905#6942905) of such "offline" DOM manupulation

Comment: Yes, detaching panel seems like a good workaround (and it performs well), but it visualy "freezes" the screen, which is not the case my customers want to see. They think, app is hang, if it is not rendering smth.